# Can AppleScript make a record with a label not known at compile time?

Tags: macos, applescript

Suppose my script contains a variable with the value `"foo"`.  How can I create a record with the value `{foo: 3}` without knowing in advance that the value might be `"foo"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think that there is another approach to your problem (especially if you are using ASObjC), but you can do this by using **run script**, for example:

```
set myLabel to text returned of (display dialog "Enter record label (key):" default answer "foo")
set myRecord to run script "return {|" & myLabel & "|:3}"

myRecord --> {foo:3} (using the default answer)
```

**Edit:** I surrounded the label (key) with pipes in case a reserved term is used.

Comment: Ah, I had an idea that what I needed was a way to turn some text into a script object, but didn't see the `run script` command.

Comment: Any way to do this with both the key and the value?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use Late Night Software's "List & Records Tools" free osax which provides the needed capability to get and set user properties.

http://www.latenightsw.com/freeware/list-record-tools/

Set myRecord to myRecord & (set user property foo in myRecord to 3)

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that this is a long answered question but it was one of the first that I found whilst researching this and attempting it myself. I also wanted the variable I was setting (Not the key) to be determined at runtime which I accomplished like so:

```
set scr to "on run argList
    return {|" & dictKey & "|: (item 1 of argList)}
    end run"

set newDict to (run script scr with parameters {dictVal})
```

Where dictKey is the variable to use as the key for the record and dictVal is the value to set it to. Hope this helps!